# Display time in local timezone when querying InfluxDB from the CLI

Tags: timezone, influxdb

I store points in InfluxDB using UTC but when querying from the [command line](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/tools/shell/),

```
influx -precision rfc3339
```

I want to display them in the local timezone, for all queries. How can I do that?

To display the time in a specific timezone, I can add (for example) `tz('America/Chicago')` to the end of each query, but this is annoying. Is there a way to configure Influx to show the time in a specific timezone for *all* queries? The CLI documentation doesn't list and argument or command to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is not possible, but you can +1 the [feature request](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/9479#issuecomment-419619256).